# Update manager keeps claims 20.10 is available, upgrade do nothing

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

Just got new Dell Vostro with 20.04 installed. After enabling to update to non-lts, update manager proposed to update to 20.10 and I agreed.
After upgardes, update manages still claims I'm on 20.04 and after "upgrade to 20.10" it does nothing and quits silently.

`sudo do-release-upgrade` does nothing. But it is suspicions "Aborting".

```
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1340 kB]                                                   
Fetched 1341 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                  
authenticate 'groovy.tar.gz' against 'groovy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'groovy.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Checking for installed snaps

Calculating snap size requirements

Updating repository information
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Here is tail of main.log

```
2021-05-13 19:43:24,296 DEBUG dir '/var/cache/apt/archives' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f2f4eadd2e0>' (136604778496.000000)
2021-05-13 19:43:24,296 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f2f4eadd2e0>' (136604778496.000000)
2021-05-13 19:43:24,297 DEBUG dir '/var' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f2f4eadd2e0>' (136604778496.000000)
2021-05-13 19:43:24,297 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '52428800' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f2f4eadd2e0>' (136604778496.000000)
2021-05-13 19:43:24,297 DEBUG dir '/boot' needs '85480317.3' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f2f4eadd2e0>' (136552349696.000000)
2021-05-13 19:43:24,297 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '5242880' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f2f4eadd2e0>' (136466869378.699997)
2021-05-13 19:43:24,297 DEBUG dir '/' needs '10485760' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f2f4eadd2e0>' (136461626498.699997)
2021-05-13 19:43:24,297 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f2f4eadd2e0>' (136451140738.699997)
2021-05-13 19:43:24,297 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f2f4eadd2e0>' (136451140738.699997)
2021-05-13 19:43:24,298 DEBUG Found writable ESP /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
2021-05-13 19:43:24,300 DEBUG demoted: 'libmpdec2 mutter'
2021-05-13 19:43:24,300 DEBUG found components: {'groovy': {'multiverse', 'universe', 'restricted', 'main'}, 'groovy-updates': {'multiverse', 'universe', 'restricted', 'main'}, 'groovy-security': {'multiverse', 'universe', 'restricted', 'main'}}
2021-05-13 19:43:24,300 DEBUG abort called
2021-05-13 19:43:24,303 DEBUG openCache()
2021-05-13 19:43:26,631 DEBUG Comparing 5.8.0-53 with 
2021-05-13 19:43:26,702 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 70409
```

Comment: Please try `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. Any errors?

Comment: No errors detected

Comment: Now disable all 3rd party repositories and try do-release-upgrade again. If it still fails and you really want 20.10 (I don't know why unless you then upgrade to 21.04) then install fresh.

Comment: I don't have any 3rd party repositories. Unless dell provdies them. How to check?
Actually, I want to upgrade to latest.

Comment: At Software&Updates > Other software you can easily check. That said, if you really want the latest then a fresh install is much faster and more reliable than 2 cycles of release upgrade.

Comment: All checkboxes are unchecked. No luck. Will try fresh then.